# BreezeJS: Retrieving large number of records via executequery() == System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: .net, entity-framework, breeze, entity-framework-6

Is System.OutOfMemoryException expected when a large number (e.g. more than 625,000) of records would be returned from a call to executequery()?

Using take() works fine, e.g.

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery
    .from("Biography")
    .select("ENTITY_ID, NAME, NICKNAME")
    .where("VAL1","==","AL")
    .orderBy("ENTITY_ID")
    .take(1000);
```

However, asking for all records results in the System.OutOfMemoryException error.

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery
    .from("Biography")
    .select("ENTITY_ID, NAME, NICKNAME")
    .where("VAL1","==","AL")
    .orderBy("ENTITY_ID");
```

Running the equivalent SQL takes about 5 seconds to complete successfully.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: When the System.OutOfMemoryException would be encountered, is the best solution to combine the results of multiple queries that use skip() and take()?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not surprised.

Just to be clear, you are trying to move more than 625,000 records over the wire and then create entities out of them. The query on the server is likely very fast, but then each of these records needs to be serialized to json, sent over the wire, and then reconstituted as an entity.  These operations can be both time consuming and memory hogs with large amount of data even with the best of implementations.

So you've got a few options to reduce both the memory footprint and the time that the operation takes.

1. Use take (per your example)
2. Use the *EntityQuery.noTracking* option.  This skips the step of converting the serialized records into 'true' entities. If you need 'true' entities later you can add them selectively to the EntityManager as needed.

Comment: I combined both options and put the following at the end of the query variable assignment: take(500000).noTracking(); This works, however going much over 500000 results in the same out of memory exception. I think I will try querying multiple times, using skip() and take(), adding records to the array each time - unless there is another way. Any idea that might be better?